# Transport Neutral Encapsulation Format なファイルを mac で読み込みたい

Tags: macos

mac 上でメールを受信していたところ、なんだかよくわからないファイルが添付されていました。

よく分からないので、ダウンロードしてみて、 `file ファイル名` コマンドを実行したところ、以下のように表示されました。

```
$ file ファイル名
ファイル名: Transport Neutral Encapsulation Format
```

これは、聞いたことないフォーマットだな、と思っています。

## 質問

- Transport Neutral Encapsulation Format を、 Mac で読み込む際に、よく使われるツールなどはありますか?

Comment: 参考: 英語版での関連質問 - [How do I handle Microsoft outlook winmail.dat? Any other surprises?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/336517)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

outlookからのメールに添付されるwinmail.dat(TNEF)を読めるようにしてくれるサイト(http://winmaildat.net/) というものもあるみたいです。
またGMailに転送すると、GMailでは読めるみたいです。
AppStoreではTNEF’s Enough というツールが良く使われているようです。